# Receiving data from Arduino to Android Device via USB

Tags: android, arduino, usb

I am trying to receive data from Arduino to my Android device. I started from [here](http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=549#app549)
In the activity part of the application, they did

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
boolean fromUser) {
if(fromUser){
if(sUsbController != null){
sUsbController.send((byte)(progress&0xFF));
      }
   }
}
```

In the send function

```
public void send(byte data) {
    mData = data;
    synchronized (sSendLock) {
        sSendLock.notify();
    }
}
```

And in the UsbRunnable part

```
private class UsbRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final UsbDevice mDevice;

    UsbRunnable(UsbDevice dev) {
        mDevice = dev;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {//here the main USB functionality is implemented
        UsbDeviceConnection conn = mUsbManager.openDevice(mDevice);
        if (!conn.claimInterface(mDevice.getInterface(1), true)) {
            return;
        }
        // Arduino Serial usb Conv
        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 34, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);
        conn.controlTransfer(0x21, 32, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte) 0x80,
                0x25, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x08 }, 7, 0);
...
...

conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, new byte[] { mData }, 1, 0);
```

So, App took the progress of the seekbar and sent it to the Arduino.
But, I want my app to receive data from Arduino. I guess I need to use bulktransfer function as well. think that I want to save the data to mData variable.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `bulkTransfer` method is the way to go. You will need to use the IN endpoint to receive the data. For instance, to get a byte of data from the Arduino use this:

```
byte[] reply = new byte[1]; // to store data from Arduino
int size = 1;               // receive at most 1 byte of data
int timeout = 100;          // try to receive data for up to 100 milliseconds
int count = conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, reply, size, timeout);

if(count < 0) {
    Log.d("ArduinoUSB", "Failure occurred when receiving from Arduino");
} else {
    Log.d("ArduinoUSB", "Received " + count + " bytes: " + Arrays.toString(reply));
}
```

The data will be stored in `reply`.